# Attempting to fix CSS-based layout problems with website

Tags: css

I've been working on the following website for my university: http://www.ecu.edu/english/tpc and have developed the layout that you currently see upon visiting it. It looks ok across browsers on the desktop, but I'm having trouble getting it to be flexible with smaller screens (such as an iPhone). I've attempted to adjust the max-width settings in a few places and I've had no luck. The specific issues are that the two horizontal menus at the top (in the HTML/CSS they are navigation and navigation2) and the content on the right (which are DTs contained in the sidebar div) seems to have fixed sizes which thus break the layout on smaller screens. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, and the full CSS can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/dSPdB/

```
/* -------- Horizontal Navigation -------- */

#navigation {
    float: left;
    margin: .5em 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: .5em 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #592a8a;
}

#navigation ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navigation li {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 11em;
    max-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em 0 0 0;
}

#navigation li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

#navigation li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

#navigation li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* --------------------------------------- */
/* -------- Navigation 2 -------- */

#navigation2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navigation2 ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navigation2 li {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-width: 3em;
    max-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em 0 0 0;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

#navigation2 li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

#navigation2 li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

#navigation2 li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation2 li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* --------------------------------------- */
```

Never mind regarding the media query not working, I didn't place it at the bottom of the CSS (duh!)

Comment: Have you considered `media queries` for smaller screen sizes?

Comment: Second that - you've got a good adaptive layout, you need to use media queries to make it a good responsive layout. Otherwise, you'll end up making too many compromises trying to make one style to rule them all.

Comment: Have you decided if you want a responsive layout or a fixed layout?

Comment: @Steve (and Adrian) - That would be nice, but honestly media queries are outside of my level of knowledge, any pointers? Wex - I would like a responsive layout if possible, wouldn't that be more accessible for desktop users?

Comment: Also, thanks @Steve for cleaning up the code, I always have trouble with large code blocks on SO

Comment: Zac, I added an answer below to show you how to handle media queries.  This is only a basic intro and you might need to read up on them a little further.  However, it shows you the basic concept and shows that they are very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you look into media queries.

Media queries are not all that difficult to use.  You still have your regular CSS and on the bottom, you add:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    ...
}
```

Inside the curly braces, you specify only the changes you want IF the screen is narrower than 480px.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    p {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

This would change all paragraph text to red, as soon as you make your browser window narrower than 480px.  Of course, this is a little silly example.  Most of the time you are more concerned about `width` or `display` of certain elements.

In your case, you probably want to target the navigation divs in those cases and have them behave differently, i.e.:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #navigation2 {
        float: none;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Note, the above is probably not what you want.  I just did some dummy changes to show what is possible.

Comment: Oh, that does look easy - I was under the impression I would need to develop entirely different style sheets for them or something. In the case of this site, I'd essentially like for it to display in one of two ways: preferably all of the screen elements "shrink" to accommodate the new size (view www.ecu.edu to see what I mean), or just stack everything up in the same order in which they are displayed in the HTML. I assume the second approach is easier.

Comment: Actually, because everything is relevant to its container, can I just target #container with the media query? I'll try that.

Comment: You can target anything you want inside the media query.  Inside it, it is just like a regular stylesheet, with the difference that it only applies to browsers windows that are narrower than 480px (in this specific case)

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it, I wonder if the problem isn't that I need to use a media query (but that may still be the answer). For the right side navigation there are definition lists with definition descriptions inside (for links). The links themselves exceed the bounds of the definition lists. But, I would have assumed that the content within the list would automatically break to fit inside of it?